# How to I make a div move left/right at a constant speed using the jQuery hover as a trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover

I trying to use jQuery's hover and animate events to make a div move left/right at a constant speed while I'm hovering over a trigger div.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#games--scroll-left').on('mouseenter', function() {
        this.iid = setInterval(function() {
           $("#gameplate-wrapper").stop().animate({ left: 20 }, 'fast');
        }, 25);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);     
    });
});
```

My thought process here is that hovering over the `#games--scroll-left` div will continually trigger the `#gameplate-wrapper` to move at a constant speed (left I think?  not sure if this would move it right or left).

But this simply isn't working.  The hover event is triggering over and over again as I planned, but nothing is happening.

How is the proper way to achieve what I'm trying to do?  My ideal functionality is while I'm hovering over the `#games--scroll-left` div, the `#gameplate-wrapper` would move left at a constant speed.  When you move the mouse outside of the scroll div, the movement will instantly stop.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If this is for a menu then you might want to consider using CSS3 for the animation. Sitepoint has a tutorial on this (http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
$('#games--scroll-left').hover( function() {
    $('#gameplate-wrapper').animate({left: 20px}, 'fast');
}, function() {
    $('#gameplate-wrapper').stop();
});
```

You can set the `left` attribute to whatever the width parameter is you wish to move to.

This will animate `#game--scroll-left` on hover and stop the animation when the user stops hovering.

If you want more information on jQuery's `.hover` function, you can find it [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Since you set left:20, it means that the box will move to the left only for 20 px and stop there. I think he wants to move the box all the way to the left. That's why he has setInterval where he tried to move 20 px to the left every 25 millisecond

Comment: Good point, that was my bad, I didn't see the 25 millisecond setting

Answer (score 0):

Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/dGqzWV)

**JS**

```
var timeToLeft = $(window).width() * 25 / 20;

$("#games-scroll-left").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#gameplate-wrapper").animate({
       marginLeft:0
   }, timeToLeft ,"linear");
});

$("#games-scroll-left").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#gameplate-wrapper").stop();
   timeToLeft = ($("#gameplate-wrapper").css("margin-left").replace("px","")) * 25 / 20;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#games-scroll-left {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#gameplate-wrapper {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: green;
   margin-left: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

In this example, I start the `#gameplate-wrapper` all the way on the right. Then hovering on `#games-scroll-left` will start it to move to the left linearly. It will stop in the middle of the animation when you hover out of `#games-scroll-left`. You can change animation time, i.e., `timeToLeft`, by changing the time step (25 millisecond in this example) and pixel increment (20 pixels in this example) to achieve your desired speed.

Answer (score 0):

To continue animate, repeat the left() function recursively until mouseleave.

```
<script>
  var animateLeft = false, animateRight = false;
  $(function() {
    $('#games--scroll-left').on('mouseenter', function() {
      animateLeft = true;
      left(); 
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
      animateLeft = false;
      $("#gameplate-wrapper").stop();      
    });
    $('#games--scroll-right').on('mouseenter', function() {
      animateRight = true;
      right(); 
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
      animateRight = false;
      $("#gameplate-wrapper").stop();
    });
  });

  function left() {
    if (!animateLeft) {
      $("#gameplate-wrapper").stop();
      return;
    }
    $("#gameplate-wrapper").animate({left: '-=20'}, 'fast', left);
  }
  function right() {
    if (!animateRight) {
      $("#gameplate-wrapper").stop();
      return;
    }
    $("#gameplate-wrapper").animate({left: '+=20'}, 'fast', right);
  }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wenkhodt/